# How to do authentication checkng in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' using URL schem parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate, url-scheme

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` here I simply check my `userName` and `password` to navigate user from `LogInVC` to `HomeVC`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if([defaults objectForKey:@"username"]!=nil  && ![[defaults objectForKey:@"password"] isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [self navigateToMaskViewController];

    } else {
        [self navigateToRSSignInViewController];

    }

    return YES;
}
```

In `openURL: sourceApplication:` here I am getting my login credentials (userName & password), which I want to use at `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` for authetication checking.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

    BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                  openURL:url
                                                        sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                               annotation:annotation
                    ];

    NSLog(@"Calling Application Bundle ID: %@", sourceApplication);
    NSLog(@"URL scheme:%@", [url scheme]);
    NSLog(@"URL query: %@", [url query]);

    if ([url query]) {
        NSMutableDictionary *queryDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        queryDict = [self getValue:[url query]];
        NSString *userName = queryDict[@"userName"];
        NSString *password = queryDict[@"password"];

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:userName forKey:@"username"];
        [defaults setObject:password forKey:@"password"];
        [defaults synchronize];

        return YES;

    } else {

    }

    return handled;
}

- (NSMutableDictionary *)getValue:(NSString *)query
{
    NSMutableDictionary *queryStringDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSArray *urlComponents = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];

    for (NSString *keyValuePair in urlComponents)
    {
        NSArray *pairComponents = [keyValuePair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        NSString *key = [[pairComponents firstObject] stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
        NSString *value = [[pairComponents lastObject] stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];

        [queryStringDictionary setObject:value forKey:key];
    }

    return queryStringDictionary;
}
```

But for URL Scheme `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` didn't call after `openURL: sourceApplication:`. So how can I do my authentication check in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`? If anyone understand it please share the solution with me. A lot of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

didFinishLaunchingWithOptions get called when you tap on the app according to app life cycle, then other delegates method or function being called accordingly

But First didFinishLaunchingWithOptions get called then it moved to your root view controller.

For Authentication checking, save your values  in [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] and then once it saved, you can check your authentication in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.